# SQL Server and MS Access 2016

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a stored procedure with multiple value parameters set up in SQL Server, but I am not sure how to call the stored procedure using a table in MS Access that serves as parameters.

Below is the parameter table in access

```
| ID | EMPLOYEE NB |
+----+-------------+ 
| 1  | A           |
| 2  | B           |
| 3  | C           |
```

The parameters in SQL Server are set up as delimited.

So it would be

```
EXEC MyStoredProcedure 'A,B,C'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this comes down to how large and how many parameters you have for the local table. I mean, if the table is only say 5, or 15 values, then no problem. However if the table is several 1000, then I can’t think passing such a long string will NOT work.

Assuming a tblParms as you have? This code would work:

```
Dim strParms      As String

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblWithParms")
   Do While .EOF = False
      If strParms <> "" Then strParms = strParms & ","
      strParms = strParms & ![MPLOYEE NB]
      .MoveNext
   Loop
End With

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
  .SQL = "EXEC MyStoreProcedure '" & strParms & "'"
  .ReturnsRecords = False
  .Execute
End With
```

If the SQL stored procedure returns records, then you would return results to a reocrdset. The above last stored procedure call code snippet would thus become

```
Dim rstReturn As DAO.Recordset

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
  .SQL = "EXEC MyStoreProcedureMrZoo '" & strParms & "'"
  .ReturnsRecords = True
  Set rstReturn = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

So the first part simply builds up the parameters you need. And the second part calls the stored procedure passing the required values. The code assumes you setup a pass through query called MyPass.